# How to persist data to DB between tests with pytest-django?

Tags: django, pytest, pytest-django

How can I persist data to DB when using pytest/pytest-django in a test-run of a Django application?

I run pytest with `py.test --nomigrations --reuse-db -s` and the Postgres DB `test_<configued_db_name>` is created as expected, however nothing seems to be persisted to DB between tests and at the end of the test run the DB is empty.

```
import pytest
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


@pytest.mark.django_db(transaction=False)
def test_insert_user():
    user = User.objects.create_user(username="test_user", email="test_user@test.com", password="test")
    users = User.objects.all()
    assert len(users) > 0

@pytest.mark.django_db(transaction=False)
def test_check_user():
    users = User.objects.all()
    assert len(users) > 0
```

The first test passes, the second does not making me wonder if anything is persisted to DB at all. According to the pystest-django documentation `@pytest.mark.django_db(transaction=False)` will not rollback whatever has been affected by the decorated test.

Thank you,

/David

Comment: This is how test runners work. If you want to use the same data in several tests you should look into fixtures in the pytest documentation.

Comment: You either should use fixtures, or something like factory_boy to have data available between tests.

Comment: Thank you. I ended up using factory_boy and pytest fixtures.

Comment: This is strange, pytest-django preserves django_migrations table contents, for example, but for all other tables the data is gone. Don't have time now to look into pytest-django sources - maybe it would be doable to have database filled with data from data migrations (pytest-django does preserve django_migrations content); on the other hand the philosophy is to use db only if needed and to create less stuff in db this way...

Comment: Had same issue BTW. It won't let me edit my comment.

Comment: I have more or less the same problem.  I have tried to create a fixture that fill the database, I have passed the fixture as argument to two test view. It works only for the first one.

Answer (score 6):

Another way of prefilling the database with data for each function is like that:

```
import pytest

from django.contrib.auth.models import User

@pytest.fixture(scope='module')
def django_db_setup(django_db_setup, django_db_blocker):
    print('setup')
    with django_db_blocker.unblock():
        User.objects.create(username='a')
        assert set(u.username for u in User.objects.all()) == {'a'}

@pytest.mark.django_db
def test1():
    print('test1')
    User.objects.create(username='b')
    assert set(u.username for u in User.objects.all()) == {'a', 'b'}

@pytest.mark.django_db
def test2():
    print('test2')
    User.objects.create(username='c')
    assert set(u.username for u in User.objects.all()) == {'a', 'c'}
```

The good thing about this method is that the setup function is only called once:

```
plugins: django-3.1.2
collected 2 items

mytest.py setup
test1
.test2
.
=================== 2 passed in 1.38 seconds ====================
```

The bad thing is that 1.38 seconds is a bit too much for such a simple test. `--reuse-db` is a faster way to do it.

Comment: It might be interesting for @dotz as well.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this problem -- prefill the DB for every function -- by defining a fixture with scope `function` (i.e. `model` and `session` will not work).

Here is the code for testing the views in Django.

```
# This is used to fill the database more easily
from mixer.backend.django import mixer

import pytest

from django.test import RequestFactory

from inventory import views
from inventory import services

pytestmark = pytest.mark.django_db

@pytest.fixture(scope="function")
def fill_db():
    """ Just filling the DB with my data """
    for elem in services.Search().get_lookup_data():
        mixer.blend('inventory.Enumeration', **elem)

def test_grid_anonymous(fill_db):
    request = RequestFactory().get('/grid/')
    response = views.items_grid(request)
    assert response.status_code == 200, \
        "Should be callable by anyone"

def test_list_anonymous(fill_db):
    request = RequestFactory().get('/')
    response = views.items_list(request)
    assert response.status_code == 200, \
        "Should be callable by anyone"
```